# Are heap elements made with unique_ptr moved to the stack still allocated on the heap?

Tags: c++, stack, smart-pointers, heap-memory

I'm having trouble understanding the behavior of unique pointers. If I allocate an object on the heap...

`std::unique_ptr<GameState> mMenuPtr(new MainMenu);`

and then `push()` and `move()` it to my GameState stack like so...

```
gameStates.push(std::move(mMenuPtr)); //pointer loses ownership of MainMenu during move
```

Is the element on the stack still dynamically allocated on the heap ? If so, does the destruction of the stack at end scope free that memory I allocated with new, or do I need some other way of destructing that object to prevent memory leaks?

I know the main purpose of `unique_ptr` is to handle deallocation for you, but after losing ownership of its object. I'm kinda clueless what to do...

Looking at the STL API it seems the only option I have is the `unique_ptr`'s get() function which allows me to re-access that object after I perform `move()`, which is what I want because I still want to be able to access that stack element across multiple files even after the `unique_ptr` destroys itself....but what would be the ideal way to do that ?

Like this ?

`GameState* statePtr = sScreen.get();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unique_ptr` will always free the object, unless `release` is called.

The `GameState` object is still allocated on the heap. Ownership of the pointer was passed to the stack/vector. The `unique_ptr` on the stack will do nothing in its destructor (since its pointer is NULL after the move), and the destructor of the stack/vector will call delete if the stack/vector is destructed before the object is moved again.

Comment: Ok to clarify that... The destruction of the stack will take care of the allocated GameState for me  ?

Comment: Yes, it calls the destructor of all its elements, which will be this unique_ptr, which then calls the destructor on its element (or nothing if NULL).